# App store says I have recently updated High Sierra but appears I'm still on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade

Yesterday I downloaded and thought I installed Sierra after being told of the available update, spending more than an hour downloading and then restarting.

I had to resign in to a few apps, e.g. Google back up and sync so it looks like something did change.

Before I made the update, if I navigated to Apple menu > About this Mac I would see the exact same screen that I see now, here it is:

[image]

10.9.5 appears to be Mavericks. From Google search:

[image]

Under Apple menu > App store > Updates, I see that Sierra was installed recently:

[image]

Am I actually on Sierra right now or am I still on Mavericks?

Comment: If you run "system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType" in Terminal, what output do you get?

Comment: @MikeScott it says ```Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.9.5 (13F1911)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0
      Boot Volume: 128GB SSD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: Mac’s MacBook
      User Name: doug (macuser)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 21 minutes

Macs-MacBook:~ macuser$ 
```

Comment: it is still offering you the 'software update" in about this mac, so click on it.

Comment: The App Store screen only say what you have downloaded, not installed. Check if the download file is still on your hard drive named "Install macOS High Sierra" in you applications folder. Once the install was successful the install file will self destruct.

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 I checked my applications folder and yes, there is a file there called "Install macOS High Sierra". I've double clicked it to follow the install wizard now. Restarting, will update here how it goes. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: OK let me make that an answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Store screen only say what you have downloaded, not installed.

Check if the download file is still on your hard drive named `"Install macOS High Sierra"` in your applications folder.

If Yes double click on it and it will start.

Once the install was successful the install file will self destruct.

Because of that I usually make a copy of it before it self destruct, so I can create a bootable USB later (when I have time for it). = Procrastinating :)